# An object containing a vector referring to another vector's content

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, vector

My problem is hard to explain, so I'll take the scenario itself as example:
I have a templated Matrix class, which is using a std::vector as storage.

What I'm looking for is having a "row", or "block" method, capable to return another Matrix with a smaller size, but referring to its parent.

With this piece of code:

```
Matrix<float> mat(2, 2);
// Filling the matrix
Matrix<float> row = mat.row(0); // returns a 1x2 matrix(row vector)
row[1] = 10; // Here I modify the row, which reflects the modifications in mat
std::cout << mat(0, 1); // prints 10
```

I have been thinking about multiple solutions but all of them have some non-negligible downsides.
Do you have any ideas about how to achieve this?
Thanks!

EDIT 1 :
I forgot to precise, the behavior should be recursive, like getting a block of another block, etc.

Comment: It is possible to pull of such a capability. However, that is a very dangerous strategy. I would advise against following up on that strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Even when implemented correctly, I'd argue that your behavior is counter-intuitive.

Make a seperate `MatrixRef` class that acts as a reference to a (subset of) a `Matrix`. This should also make implementation fairly straightforward.

Comment: I've thinked about it, the problem is that the Matrix class possesses some functions like "sum", "trace", and I'd like to use them on the referred Block as well..

Comment: @Raakz Then implement them for a `MatrixRef` argument as well :)

Comment: If its the only solution, I'll go for it, I just thought it was a bit repetitive to do so

Comment: @Raakz Use [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to code the functions only once.